# PHP Помогите составить регулярное выражение для разбора URL

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необхадимо составить регулярное выражение котрое бы удовлетворяло шаблону.

Дано: /project_name/en/alias-i7878.html

На выходе должен получить такие значения

**project_name**

**en**

**alias**

**i**

**7878**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот пожалуйста: **/\/(\w+)\/(\w{2})\/(\w+)\-(\w)(\d+)/ui**

На выходе: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сайт для написания и тестирования регулярок https://regex101.com/